# FilePond and jQuery: Add an existing file without uploading it again

Tags: jquery, filepond

I am trying to add an already uploaded file into FilePond field.

This bit of code is working except that it uploads the file again. I just need to add the file information in the data and not uploading it again as it was already uploaded:

```
$('.my-pond').first().filepond('addFile', 'archive.zip').then(function(file){
      console.log('file added', file);
    });
```

Someone has any idea about how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After stumbling on this (old) post, and doing some digging myself I've found the solution.

When creating the filepond instance, setting the options it is needed to add the `load()` function to the server object. The `load` function generates a blob from the remote image when a file is set.

For example:

```
load: (source, load, error, progress, abort, headers) => {
    var myRequest = new Request(source);
    fetch(myRequest).then((res) => {
        return res.blob();
    }).then(load);
}
```

Now you can set the default image two ways.

Adding the file by setting it directly in the options when creating the filepond instance. For example:

```
// File is directly added via options
let pond = FilePond.create(field, {
    files: [
        {
            source: FULL_IMAGE_URL,
            options: {
                type: 'local'
            }
        }
    ],
    server: {
        url: API_URL,
        process: '/fileprocess',
        revert: '/filerevert',
        load: (source, load, error, progress, abort, headers) => {
            var myRequest = new Request(source);
            fetch(myRequest).then((res) => {
                return res.blob();
            }).then(load);
        },
    }
})
```

OR by adding the file after the instance is created

```
// Creating the filepond instance, without adding a default image
let pond = FilePond.create(field, {
    server: {
        url: API_URL,
        process: '/fileprocess',
        revert: '/filerevert',
        load: (source, load, error, progress, abort, headers) => {
            var myRequest = new Request(source);
            fetch(myRequest).then((res) => {
                return res.blob();
            }).then(load);
        },
    }
})

// ... Some other function() {
    pond.setOptions({
        files: [
            {
                source: FULL_IMAGE_URL,
                options: {
                    type: 'local'
                }
            }
        ]
    });
// }
```

Sources:

- `setOptions` https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/instance/methods/#setting-options
- `Server:load()` https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/server/#load

Answer (score 1):

This method is not used that way, it is used for uploading files. I'm also looking for ways to add existing files.

Refer to https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/instance/properties/#files